# List of Application in Android

Tags: java, android, package-managers

I am following the code given in the below link:

http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/06/12/create-application-launcher-as-a-list/

to list out installed application on my phone.

But the problem here is that it is listing all the applications.

**All system related apps also like.**

Network Location,
Sound Search for Google play,
Launcher,
Package access helper

How do I filter not to show non-launchable apps?

I tried the following:

Instead of this

```
  c.getPackageManager().getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA)
```

I tried:

```
  c.getPackageManager().getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_UNINSTALLED_PACKAGES)
```

But same result.

Can somebody help me out with this please?

Thanks!

UPDATE:

Thanks to MH for guiding. Now I am able to see only installed app's from playstore. How to do also get System default apps like Gmail, Clock, settings, Google maps etc.

Here is what I tried:

```
    List<ApplicationInfo> appInfos = c.getPackageManager().getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
    List<ApplicationInfo> userAppInfos = new ArrayList<ApplicationInfo>();
    List<ApplicationInfo> systemAppInfos = new ArrayList<ApplicationInfo>();
    for (ApplicationInfo info : appInfos) 
    {
        if ((info.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) != 0) 
        {
            systemAppInfos.add(info);
        }
        else
        {
            userAppInfos.add(info);
        }
    }
    return userAppInfos;
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you mean about 'only specific apps?  If you want to filter out non-launchable apps or packages (for example, only want to show apps which displaying in apps screens), you can use [queryIntentActivities](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#queryIntentActivities%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) method in PackageManager w/ a proper intent instead of getInstalledApplications.

```
    final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    List<ResolveInfo> list = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);

    if( list != null ){
        for( ResolveInfo resolveInfo : list ){
            Log.d("Apps", resolveInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick note. Looks like I can't update the code with the code given in the example project. Is this possible, if so How?

Comment: You can just fix some part of AppInfoAdapter adapter in example. If you check the [ResolveInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ResolveInfo.html) class that I used, there is activityInfo field already there, so you can just use it.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to get a list of installed applications but filter out any system apps. If that's indeed the case, you can use the returned `ApplicationInfo` instances to determine whether the app is consider a system app or a regular, user-installed app.

Suppose we wanted to split the installed applications into two lists: one with system apps and one with downloaded apps. We could do that as follows:

```
List<ApplicationInfo> appInfos = getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
List<ApplicationInfo> userAppInfos = new ArrayList<ApplicationInfo>();
List<ApplicationInfo> systemAppInfos = new ArrayList<ApplicationInfo>();
for (ApplicationInfo info : appInfos) {
    if (info.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM != 0) systemAppInfos.add(info);
    else userAppInfos.add(info);
}
```

Note that the `ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM` constant indicates:

> If set, this application is installed in the device's system image.

You may or may not also want to do something with `ApplicationInfo.FLAG_UPDATED_SYSTEM_APP`:

> This is set if this application has been installed as an update to a built-in system application.

Comment: Thanks for the quick note..Looks like I can't update the code on the following package shown in this tutorial. 

http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/06/12/create-application-launcher-as-a-list/

Is it possible, if so how?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If you want to change the list of displayed apps in the tutorial, just change the list that is passed into the `AppInfoAdapter`. Using the example in my answer: basically the tutorial is now passing in `appInfos`, but if you copy-paste some of the code above, you could pass on `userAppInfos` in stead to display a subset of the full list.

Comment: How do I do it? The tutorial code:

public static List getInstalledApplication(Context c) 
 {
  return c.getPackageManager().getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
 }

What would I return in this case with your sample code? can you please help me out with snippet. 

Thanks!

Comment: I tried it.. Works. But the problem is that I am not able to get any default applications like Gmail App, Clock, Settings... This is shows only list items that are installed by user.